# How to do correlation in multiple ordinal variables?

Tags: correlation, anova, ordinal-data, likert

I have five likert scaled variables (with 5 categories each). Variable 1-4 meassure one construct (let us say love) and will be the independent variable. Variable 5 will be the dependent variable. Now my questions:

1. Can I sum up 1-4, build a new variable and handle it as intervall scaled?
2. What method do I have to use to calculate the correlation?

According to what I know 1. is yes and 2. is Anova but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can build a simple additive index by summing responses across 4 variables but I would be reluctant calling that an interval variable.  If difference between 1-2 is not the same as 3-4 then why would a difference in the index values be comparable???  And why does it need to be interval in the first place?  Run an ordered probit on your 5th likert-based variable and use the index as an independent variable.
2. for correlations in categorical variables use Spearman Rho